# PHP - Replace Same Character With Different Ones in String

Tags: php

I have a file that contains certain data in `Name|Address|Email|Phone` format. Each line contains the data in the said format for each customer. How do I implode or str_replace to get the format below?

```
Name: <br>
Address: <br>
Email: <br>
Phone: <br>
```

I have the idea and thought mapped out but I can't seem to be able to implement it.

**N:B -** `Name|Address|Email|Phone` is the format not the data in itself. The data would look something like `Foo Bar|123, Foo Lane|foo@bar.com|123-456-7890`

Comment: `str_replace('|', ': <br />', 'Name|Address|Email|Phone')`?

Comment: Name|Address|Email|Phone is the format not the data in itself. The data would look something like Foo Bar|123, Foo Lane|foo@bar.com|123-456-7890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume something like this should help:

```
$data = explode('|', 'Foo Bar|123, Foo Lane|foo@bar.com|123-456-7890');
$keys = ['Name', 'Address' ,'Email', 'Phone'];

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = $keys[$k] . ': ' . $v;
}
echo implode('<br />', $result);
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/hlDaa).

Comment: Thanks. Did exactly what I required and is pretty much elegant. I'll just tweak it to work my entire file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$lineBreak = "<br/>";
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
 echo $line = str_replace('|', ":".$lineBreak, $line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use str_getcsv and swap your delimiter for the pipe.

The first part can be swapped out.  Just iterate a line/row at a time.

```
<?php
function get_line() {
    $data =<<<DATA
Holmes|Baker Street|sherlock@example.com|01234 56789
Mouse|Baker Street|danger@example.com|01234 67890
DATA;

    foreach(explode("\n", $data) as $line)
        yield $line;
}

foreach(get_line() as $line) {
    list($name, $address, $email, $phone) = str_getcsv($line, '|');
    echo 'Name: '    . $name    . '<br />';
    echo 'Address: ' . $address . '<br />';
    echo 'Email: '   . $email   . '<br />';
    echo 'Phone: '   . $phone   . '<br />';
}
```

Output:

`Name: Holmes<br />Address: Baker Street<br />Email: sherlock@example.com<br />Phone: 01234 56789<br />Name: Mouse<br />Address: Baker Street<br />Email: danger@example.com<br />Phone: 01234 67890<br />`